# My form don't found value and slide-toggle are always checked

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with my forms.  In web all my slide-toggle are checked like in .[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWspk.png)

I think that problem is in `patchFor(){}` Can you look my code please?
I try this code:

ts:

```
homeboxsp: Package[] = [];   
activeHomeboxPForm: FormGroup;

this.activeHomeboxPForm = this.fb.group({
  'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)

}); 

populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.hsP.homeboxPGetAll().subscribe(
        homeboxsp => {
            this.homeboxsp = homeboxsp;
            this.patchForm();
        }
    )
}
patchForm() {
    this.activeHomeboxPForm.patchValue({
        active: this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.active),
        homeboxpackage_id: this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id)
    });
    console.log(this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.active))
    console.log(this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id))
}
```

console show my value. [imageformconsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntKy1.png)

and html:

```
<form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm" class="col s12" materialize>
    <section class="example-section">
        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" value="active"
        class="example-margin"
        [color]="color" [checked]="checked"
        (click)="onActiveHomeboxP(item.homeboxpackage_id, item.active)">
            {{item.active}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
    </section>
</form>
```

Please can you suggest me what is wrong in this code?  Thank you

My exp: [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cw81dl?file=app%2Fservice.ts)

**Update Code:**
ts code:

```
this.activeHomeboxPForm = new FormGroup({
  'active': new FormControl(true, Validators.required),
  'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)

});
  populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.ws.homeboxPGetAll().subscribe(
      homeboxsp => {
        this.homeboxsp = homeboxsp.map((homeboxspp) => {
        this.activeHomeboxPForm.controls['active'].setValue(homeboxspp.active),
        this.activeHomeboxPForm.controls['homeboxpackage_id'].setValue(homeboxspp.homeboxpackage_id)
          console.log(homeboxspp)
          console.log(homeboxspp.active)
          console.log(homeboxspp.homeboxpackage_id)
          return new HomeboxP(homeboxspp);

        });
      }
    )
  }
```

html code:

```
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp; let i=index">
       <td> 
        <form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm" class="col s12"> 
          <section class="example-section">
            <mat-slide-toggle  formControlName="active" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.active === '1'"> {{item.active}}
            </mat-slide-toggle>
          </section>
          </form>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

image:
[image]

in console looks good, but in html doesn't display, active = 1 checked and active = 0 no checked. Please any idea how to implement?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: seems you use pathValue not correctly, its argument should be value for the form element, but you pass array of three values [1,0,0]

Comment: @DicBrus please can you write code? Thnx

Comment: @bugs how to show in html slide-toggle checked when acitve = 1 and not checked when active=0

Comment: @DicBrus please, can you write some code, how to solve this problem? Thnx

Comment: I looked into your code that you shared, and I've the same question as was asked here, I see only one toggle element, not three. How did you manage to get three (as you show at the picture).

Comment: homeboxPGetAll() --> this get me all product

Comment: this `homeboxPGetAll` retrieves data for the form. My ask is about form itself, as I see in your code and in stackblitz  that you shared - there is only one slide element in the form. But you state that you have three slides, that is not clear.

Comment: Please look my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cw81dl?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: you have three slide-toggles that are managed by the only one variable `myform`

thus patching value in this variable, it has impact to all three slide-toggles.

What you need: myform should be an array that contains data for all three slide-toggles, and then patching it, you will get expected result.

Comment: @OnaBi Have you managed to fix your issue?

Comment: Below I published working demo and explanation

Comment: Thank you for your answer, looks good, but for me doesn't work. I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the same `formControlName` for all your sliders

Try setting a unique control name

```
<div *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp;let index=i">
 <form [formGroup]="myform" class="col s12">
          <section class="example-section">
            <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active-{{i}}"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afrebm?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Whether a slide is checked or not is defined with the `[checked]` property, so if you want your sliders to reflect the `active` property of your elements you need something like

```
<form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm" class="col s12" materialize>
    <section class="example-section">
        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" value="active"
        class="example-margin"
        [color]="color" [checked]="item.active"
        (click)="onActiveHomeboxP(item.homeboxpackage_id, item.active)">
            {{item.active}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
    </section>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhuwfg)

Comment: I try this, but nothing change

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cw81dl?file=app/app.component.ts Please look my code

Comment: The code looks quite confusing, but I've modified your snippet so that it behaves as required, see if that helps

Comment: Now I try this code but for me doesn't work. When I remove formControlName="active" my all value are unchecked. I dont understan what is the problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj445k)

Actually what was done: I turned `myform` to contain all three slide-toggles and changed `patchForm` function:

Note changes in template `[formGroup]="myform[i]"`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `  
    <div *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp; let i = index">
      <form [formGroup]="myform[i]" class="col s12">
          <section class="example-section">
            <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" value="active" class="example-margin" [color]="color" [checked]="item.active" (click)="onActiveHomeboxP()"> {{item.active}}
          </mat-slide-toggle>
          </section>
        </form>
   </div>
  `
})
```

Changes in myForm declaration:

```
myform: FormGroup[];

constructor(public service: Service) {
...
    this.myform = [
      new FormGroup(
        {
         'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
         'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        }),
      new FormGroup(
       {
         'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
         'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
       }),
      new FormGroup(   
        {
          'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        })
      ];
}
```

And at least changes in `patchForm`:

```
patchForm() {
  this.homeboxsp.forEach((val,i) => {
    this.myform[i].patchValue(
    {active: val.active == "1", homeboxpackage_id: val.homeboxpackage_id}
  )
});
```

Comment: This example doesn't work for me. I try other example, like in post, can you look and suggest something please?