# how to show in html slide-toggle checked when acitve = 1 and not checked when active=0?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, slidetoggle

I have a problem with my mat-slide-toggle. In web all my slide-toggle are checked like in .image[image]

I think that all of things are good, but in html display all checked. Please, can you suggest me any solution? I try to use, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575660/my-form-dont-found-value-and-slide-toggle-are-always-checked) but nothing work for me.
My code:

ts code:

```
this.activeHomeboxPForm = new FormGroup({
  'active': new FormControl(true, Validators.required),
  'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)

});
  populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.ws.homeboxPGetAll().subscribe(
      homeboxsp => {
        this.homeboxsp = homeboxsp.map((homeboxspp) => {
        this.activeHomeboxPForm.controls['active'].setValue(homeboxspp.active),
        this.activeHomeboxPForm.controls['homeboxpackage_id'].setValue(homeboxspp.homeboxpackage_id)
          console.log(homeboxspp)
          console.log(homeboxspp.active)
          console.log(homeboxspp.homeboxpackage_id)
          return new HomeboxP(homeboxspp);

        });
      }
    )
  }
```

html code:

```
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp; let i=index">
       <td> 
        <form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm" class="col s12"> 
          <section class="example-section">
            <mat-slide-toggle  formControlName="active" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.active === '1'"> {{item.active}}
            </mat-slide-toggle>
          </section>
          </form>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

[image: imageconsole]

in console looks good, but in html doesn't display, active = 1 checked and active = 0 no checked. Please any idea how to implement?

**Update code:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp; let i=index">
   <td> 
    <form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm" class="col s12"> 
      <section class="example-section">
        <mat-slide-toggle  formControlName="active-{{i}}" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.active === '1'"> {{item.active}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
      </section>
      </form>
  </td>
```

show this: 
[image: error]

Comment: what do yu want exactly? to show the slider is active = 1 and hide it otherwise?

Comment: [checked]="item.active === '1'" --- Are you sure that the value behind active is a string? What happens if you compare this way? [checked]="item.active == '1'"

Comment: @DiabolicWords my active is number. I try and [checked]="item.active ==1" but nothing change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My form don't found value and slide-toggle are always checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575660/my-form-dont-found-value-and-slide-toggle-are-always-checked)

Comment: @David I want to show in html slide checked where active are 1, and no checked where active = 0

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @David yes I know that is the same question, but I don't solution this problem.

Comment: Did you try my solution below?

Comment: @Vega sorry, what can I remove?

Comment: Yes, I remove it, but the error show again in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html displays all sliders as checked because you gave them all the same `formControlName`

Change it to

```
    <form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm" class="col s12"> 
<tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp; let i=index">
   <td> 

      <section class="example-section">
        <mat-slide-toggle  formControlName="active-{{i}}" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.active === '1'"> {{item.active}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
      </section>
      </form>
  </td>
```

**Edit**

You can also use one unique form group for all your sliders

```
let controls = {
  'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
};

for(let i = 0;i <  this.homeboxsp.length;i++)
{
  controls['active-'+i] = new FormControl(this.homeboxsp[i].active =='1', Validators.required)
}
    this.myform = new FormGroup(controls);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afrebm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: David, in page display good, my product active are checked, and product active 0 are not checked. But in console show error like in update post. Thank you

Comment: David how are you? Yes I know that is different question, but please, I can not leave a new post. In this post, I need to change the switch  only when I press OK. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmznlu?file=app/app.component.ts Thank you

Comment: how are you? I have a problem with this code when I navigate in paginate. When i navigate in pagin 2, or 3, show all slide-toggle that are active or not active like in pagine 1 :( please, what is the problem? I need your help please

Comment: Just open another question I'll have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398726/how-to-make-controls-to-works-correctly-and-when-navigate-in-another-paginate my new questin. I create new account because I have reached my question limit. Thnks a lot

Comment: Please, look my demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbzrma?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: David, I'm sorry, I'm disturbing you for this problem. Please I need your help. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbzrma?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it was intended or not but Angular Material Slide toggle dosn't work well with formcontrols. Here is a workaround:

**Typescript:**

```
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      active: new FormControl(true, Validators.required),
      homeboxpackage_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      inactive: new FormControl(false, Validators.required),
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
...
   formControlName="{{item.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}}" class="example-margin"> {{item.active}}
...
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnezwk)**

Comment: I tried your code, works good, but I have a problem when I navigate in paginate. So if I am in paginate 2,when I active a product in this pagin, my all product activated (only checked), and  when I deactivated a product, all product deactivated. Please, I need your help. Thank you

Comment: Could you update the above demo to demonstrate what's going on? It's kind of unclear what's going on

Comment: Please, look my demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bcrnc?file=app/app.component.html