# How to make controls to works correctly and when navigate in another paginate

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular5, slidetoggle

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668800/how-to-show-in-html-slide-toggle-checked-when-acitve-1-and-not-checked-when-ac) to use the slider. I have a problem with the controller when I go to the next page. On the front page the controller works very well, when I go to the second page, the same values are repeated. So if on page 1 the product 1 in the first line is active, even on the second page, the product in the first line is active. But really the product is not active on the second page. The same thing is repeated on the other pages. Every page the first line has active. I think the problem is in my code ts.
 [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbzrma?file=app/app.component.html)
Please follow my code below:

```
  populateFormGPS() {
    this.ws.getAllGpss().subscribe(
      gpss => {
        this.gpss = gpss
        console.log(gpss)// all value arrive ok
        let controls = {
          'gps_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < this.gpss.length; i++) {
          controls['gps_actived-' + i] = new FormControl(this.gpss[i].gps_actived === 1, Validators.required)
        }
        this.acitveGPSForm = new FormGroup(controls);
        this.patchForm();
      }
    )
  }

  patchForm() {
    this.acitveGPSForm.patchValue({
      gps_id: this.gpss.map(x => x.gps_id),
    });
  }
```

Html code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m2">
    <label class="col s12 label-control" style="padding: 0px">Rows on page</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="rowsOnPage">
        <option [ngValue]="5">5</option>
        <option [ngValue]="10">10</option>
      <option [ngValue]="20">20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m4">
    <label class="col s12 label-control" style="padding: 0">Sort by</label>
    <div class="col s6" style="padding: 0">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="sortBy">
       ..................
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6" style="padding: 0">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="sortOrder">
       ............
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <table class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]="gpss | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"
    [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Serial No. </th>
        <th>IMEI </th>
        <th>SIM no</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i=index">
        <td>{{item.gps_serial}}</td>
        <td>{{item.gps_imei}}</td>
        <td>{{item.gps_sim_iccid}}</td>
        <td>{{item.unit_price}} ALL</td>
        <td>
          <form [formGroup]="acitveGPSForm" class="col s12" *ngIf="auths.findPermission('gpsactivate')">
              <section class="example-section" >
                <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="gps_actived-{{i}}" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.gps_actived ===1" #elem (click)="onActivegps(item.gps_id, item.gps_actived, elem)" >
                </mat-slide-toggle>
              </section>
          </form>
          <td>
         .............
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td colspan="5">
        <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,20]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
      </td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please, any idea, how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your control names are based on local indexes instead of Ids.  So when your rows are filtered to display `n` results per page, your row `n` will have index 0, so it'll reuse the same form control as for actual row 0.

In **app.component.ts**, replace

```
controls['active-'+i] = ...
```

with

```
controls['active-'+this.homeboxsp[i].homeboxpackage_id] = ...
```

And on **app.component.html**, replace

```
formControlName="active-{{i}}"
```

with

```
formControlName="active-{{item.homeboxpackage_id}}"
```

[Modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahjk64?file=app/app.component.ts)